# Divide each row by the total of a subcategory

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have a Postgres table like:

```
id | value | category
0  | 10    | a
1  | 11    | b
2  | 50    | b
3  | 20    | a
```

and I want the following (where the expression in the last column is evaluated, of course):

```
id | value | category | weight
0  | 10    | a        | 10 / (10+20)
1  | 11    | b        | 11 / (11+50)
2  | 50    | b        | 50 / (11+50)
3  | 20    | a        | 20 / (10+20)
```

Using 2 queries you could first aggregate the per-category totals into a temporary table using `select category, sum(value) from table0 group by category`, and then divide the original table by the temporary table (by matching the category).

But how can I do this in Postgres in a single query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html) for that: [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/DZRrVvzF)

```sql
SELECT t1."id"
     , t1."value"
     , t1."category"
     , t1."value"::decimal / SUM(t1."value") OVER w1 AS "div_1"
FROM tab1 AS t1
WINDOW w1 AS (PARTITION BY t1."category")
ORDER BY t1."id";
```

| id | value | category | div_1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 10 | a | 0.33333333333333333333 |
| 1 | 11 | b | 0.18032786885245901639 |
| 2 | 50 | b | 0.81967213114754098361 |
| 3 | 20 | a | 0.66666666666666666667 |

Answer (score 1):

I hope this might help you

First Create Table named "t"

```
CREATE TABLE t (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  value Float NOT NULL,
  category CHAR(1) NOT NULL
);
```

Insert Data into table

```
INSERT INTO t (id, value, category)
VALUES (0, 10, 'a'), (1, 11, 'b'), (2, 50, 'b'), (3, 20, 'a');
```

Data in table

```
id  value   category
0   10         a
1   11         b
2   50         b
3   20         a
```

Now Query

```
SELECT t.id, t.value, t.category, t.value /  ct.total_value AS weight
FROM  t
JOIN (
  SELECT category, SUM(value) AS total_value
  FROM t
  GROUP BY category
) ct ON t.category = ct.category
ORDER BY t.id;
```

Result

```
id  value   category    weight
0   10        a         0.333333333333333
1   11        b         0.180327868852459
2   50        b         0.819672131147541
3   20        a         0.666666666666667
```

Comment: But this more than one operation =)